# Para que serve o Hermes?

Tags: javascript, react-native

Vi que o [Hermes](https://github.com/facebook/hermes) é uma *engine de JavaScript* e que foi desenvolvido pelo Facebook para o React Native, sendo recentemente adicionado para o Android na [versão 0.60.1](https://github.com/react-native-community/releases/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#v0601) e posteriormente para o iOS na [versão 0.64.0](https://reactnative.dev/blog/2021/03/12/version-0.64).

Mas se já tínhamos outras *engines* de JavaScript, para que serve o Hermes? Ele possui algum diferencial?

Comment: Tem a DOC aqui: https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

Comment: A documentação é mais focada em relação ao código - como habilitar, saber se está habilitado, cuidados com versionamento etc. Só as primeiras duas frases do primeiro parágrafo falam sobre o Hermes em si

Comment: No blog de devs do Facebook tem [esse post](https://engineering.fb.com/2019/07/12/android/hermes/) que explica melhor porque criaram outra engine. E tem [este post](https://dev.to/godswillokokon/react-native-what-you-need-to-know-about-hermes-4lhn) no dev.to com mais opiniões de terceiros que podem esclarecer um pouco mais a motivação de criar o Hermes.

Answer (score 0):

Hermes é uma engine de JavaScript otimizada para aplicativos mobile desenvolvidos com React Native. O objetivo do Hermes é fornecer uma performance aprimorada e um tamanho de arquivo menor para esses aplicativos, tornando-os mais rápidos e fáceis de carregar.

Uma das principais vantagens do Hermes é que ele é uma engine de JavaScript compacta e otimizada, o que significa que ela é menor em tamanho e mais rápida do que outras engines de JavaScript, como o JavaScriptCore, que é usado no iOS, ou o V8, que é usado no Android. Isso pode resultar em aplicativos mais leves e rápidos, o que é especialmente importante em dispositivos com hardware limitado ou em áreas com conexões de internet lentas.

Além disso, o Hermes também oferece suporte a características avançadas de otimização de memória, como a compactação de objetos de heap, o que pode ajudar a reduzir o uso de memória e a melhorar a performance geral do aplicativo.

Em resumo, o Hermes foi criado para fornecer uma performance aprimorada e um tamanho de arquivo menor para aplicativos mobile desenvolvidos com React Native, o que pode ser especialmente útil em dispositivos com hardware limitado ou em áreas com conexões de internet lentas.

**Refs:**

Página oficial do Hermes no site do React Native:

https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes

Artigo introduzindo o Hermes no blog do Facebook:

https://engineering.fb.com/react-native/hermes/

Repositório do Hermes no GitHub:

https://github.com/facebook/hermes

Answer (score -3):

Hermes é um JavaScript Engine de código aberto projetado para executar aplicativos React Native no Android. O uso do Hermes será provavelmente o metodo mais adotado de executar aplicativos do React Native no futuro.

Diferença da outras Engines:
Hermes se destaca de outras engines pelo seu desempenho quando se trata de tempo de inicialização (usando a pré-compilação em um bytecode), uso de memória e tamanho do aplicativo.

Answer (score -3):

O Hermes tem a incumbência de melhorar o desempenho do aplicativo React Native em um ambiente mobile. Dando mais performance e agilidade.

Answer (score -3):

O foco da Hermes está em obter desempenho sem usar necessariamente um JIT (de modo a também ser útil no iOS e evitar os tempos de warmup de outras abordagens). Ao gerar um aplicativo em modo produção, ela converte o código javascript numa espécie de bytecode em tempo de build, evitando também a perda de tempo com parse de código texto, que no caso do javascript é razoavelmente complexo, vide detalhes do lançamento no [blog](https://engineering.fb.com/2019/07/12/android/hermes/)

Comment: Você pode colocar um link para a documentação ou fonte de onde vem essa informação para referências futuras.

Answer (score -4):

Basicamente o Hermes foi desenvolvido para acelerar a inicialização de aplicativos usando **otimização estática** e **compact bytecode** com isso ele é capaz de melhorar significativamente o tempo de inicialização, o tamanho da APK gerada além de otimizar a utilização de memória usando Garbage Collector Strategy with noncontagious.